# ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'django' when i tried to start

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

**I tried to set up the Apollo and React environment.**

> This is material that I used https://github.com/mbrochh/react-apollo-graphql-demo

**when the error occurred?**

whe i did

./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Comment: try running `pip install -r requirements.txt` after entering backend directory.

Comment: @Hisham___Pak Thanks  i did 
but next error occurs
watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:

Comment: @Hisham___Pak.Finally, I solved it. but I opened up the server and tried to /graphiql/` but it didn't work